# How to Connect to office workstation from linux machine?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, linux-mint

I'm a newbie to Linux, I have installed Linux mint maya 13. I would like to connect to my office machine from this Linux version. I am actually an Intermediate level windows user, using it for the last 6 years. Very lately turned to Linux, at least now realized that Linux is worth working on.

Earlier in windows environment, this is how I would connect to office machine and do work.

- Connect to Cisco VPN. I have put some VPN profile files in the cisco installed folder VPN profiles.
- Do an mstsc from start->run
- Login to remote machine.

How can I do a remote desktop connection from this Linux Esp. Linux mint maya. 
Is there a similar analogy or how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're connecting to a windows machine?

Comment: Yes. I am connecting to windows box.

Comment: Just read the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6773/1) is some reasonably recent documentation on the Cisco VPN client for Linux, which should explain what to do with profile files &c.; once you're on the VPN, you can use `tsclient` (which is probably available from your package manager, if not already installed) in place of `mstsc`.

Comment: I have done as suggested, First installed vpnc and created a new VPn connection imported pcf files. When I try to connect, it's asking group password, I have checked my PCF file it's empty over there. So left blank. When I hover on network connection it says "user authentication required for VPN connection Ind_US(this is connection name)". And its refreshing continuously. What to do?

Comment: You may need to check with your IT department for the necessary shared secret -- from the linked documentation: "Enter the group password you were given by the VPN administrator into this Web page, and use the result as your group password: http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/bin/cisco-decode." If you're uncomfortable doing that (looks safe enough, it doesn't ask any other info so there'd be nothing to tie that password to your VPN), you could always download cisco-decrypt.c (linked on the decoder page), compile it, and run it by hand to produce the same result.

Comment: An UPDATE: Somehow, I can now connect to VPN and can see a lock symbol out there. But cannot ping my machine Say abc.domain._.com.
But when I pinged the VPN connection ip address it resulted good.How to connect to our desired machine?

Comment: Try pinging the IP address to which abc.domain._.com resolves. If you get an answer, the issue is with DNS resolution; try adding your company's internal nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf. Otherwise (and assuming the machine you're pinging is set up to answer pings), it's to do with your routing tables. Judging by http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/cisco-vpn-client-routing-problem-on-debian-sarge-267410/ -- I'm not sure whether you're likely to get a good result...

Comment: OMG! It's working thanks. By giving Ip address it works. The look and feel is like as if I'm seeing new world :)

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'd change from the above answer: I'd personally recommend Remmina over tsclient.

Comment: I haven't needed to do this from Linux in so long that I'd never heard of Remmina. In any case, this really belongs as a comment to my answer rather than an answer itself.

Comment: @pnuts Because Jim Salter's response isn't actually an answer, i.e., it doesn't offer a solution to the problem posed in srk's question. Instead, it's an additional piece of advice offered as an expansion to the answer I gave, and that's exactly the purpose for which comments on answers are intended -- that's actually why they were added in the first place.

Comment: @pnuts Not having recommended the answer for deletion, I can't really answer your arguments here, other than to note that I also value the recommendation of Remmina. (I suppose that, not having recommended deletion, I shouldn't really have posted my previous comment -- that said, it does, I think, explain why the recommendations occurred.)